# How ro get Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 22.04.01

Tags: dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS 64-bit, Kernel Linux 5.15.0-58-generic x86_64, Memory 3.5 GiB, and KDE Partition Manager with partition 297 GB empty & available.
I downloaded Windows 7 "all in one" ISO from https://archive.org/details/windows-7-install-iso. The question is how to "burn" that ISO to jack-flash (if necessary) and how to get Windows 7 installed to the above partition for dual boot?

Comment: Note that Windows 7 support has ended, do not connect to Internet. Is Ubuntu UEFI or BIOS install. You have to install in same boot mode. Windows only installs to gpt drives in UEFI mode & only to MBR(msdos) drives in BIOS mode. And UEFI Secure Boot must be off as Windows 7 does not support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a bootable flash drive with [rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.21/rufus-3.21.exe) latest version is 3.21. Use some windows machine to make the bootable flashdrive! Or burn .iso to a DVD.

1. Fist install Windows 7 from the prepared image;
2. Then install Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS 64-bit, which will make yours grub2 with dual-boot

Comment: I downloaded Rufus 3.21. But the official site says, "System Requirements: Windows 7 or later ..." It does not work in Ubuntu per its manual. Can I install Windows as second OS without "deleting" my Ubuntu?

Comment: When you install windows it will delete grub2 if it is preinstalled, and that's why you have to install Ubuntu as second OS, because it make grub2 and give you options to choose which OS you want to use! The same is with all windows distributions.